# Kotlin - How to prevent null gets into Map object during jackson Json deserialization?

Tags: json, kotlin, jackson, non-nullable

Firstly let me past some runnable code to help you get the issue I want to solve:

(maven dependency to include if you want to run this example code)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

simply create a Kotlin file and past the runnable code below in:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.readValue

data class MapObject(val map: Map<String, String>, val age: Int)
data class SimpleObject(val name:String, val age: Int)
data class MapSimpleObject(val map: SimpleObject, val age: Int)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()

    val mObj: MapObject = mapper.readValue("""{"map": {"name": null}, "age": 1}""")
    println(mObj)  // mObj can be created, print "MapObject(map={name=null}, age=1)", which is not nice

    val msObj: MapSimpleObject = mapper.readValue("""{"map": {"name": null, "age": 1}, "age": 1}""")
    println(msObj)  // throw MissingKotlinParameterException at line above, which is nice

    val sObj: SimpleObject = mapper.readValue("""{"name": null, "age": 1}""")
    println(sObj)  // throw MissingKotlinParameterException at line above, which is nice

    // val m: Map<String, Int> = mapOf(null to 2)  // won't compile, which is nice
}
```

As you can see, specifically for `val mObj: MapObject`, even `MapObject`'s `map` is a Map defined in Kotlin with Non-Null Types, one can still create object with Json payload such as `{"map": {"name": null}, "age": 1}`, resulting `mObj` object as `MapObject(map={name=null}, age=1)`

This is not what I wanted, I would like Kotlin's null safety feature to capture this and throw me some exceptions if I put json payload like that.

So how can I make sure `null` is not injected if I have data class structure like `data class MapObject(val map: Map<String, String>, val age: Int)`?

Comment: cool, after huge searching I could'n find any possibility to avoid this behaviour. 
`@JsonSetter(contentNulls = Nulls.FAIL, nulls = Nulls.FAIL)` must enable failing on null (if I understand it right) but it don't. So I see two possible solutions:
1) deserialise with null values and after filter it
2) write custom deserialisation

Comment: I was going to suggest similar stuff as kurt mentions: Create an extension function that checks for nulls previous to read value. That's the only idea and as @jingx mentions, there's no way to avoid nulls via reflection.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, Kotlin's null safety is mostly compile-time. There is nothing preventing `null` from being set into a non-nullable property at runtime via reflection, as [Kotlin reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) states:

> ...The only possible causes of NPE's may be:
>
> Java interoperation: ...
>   Generic types used for Java interoperation with incorrect nullability, e.g. a piece of Java code might add null into a Kotlin MutableList, meaning that MutableList should be used for working with it;